# How to run NUnit onetimesetup multiple times for different databases

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, nunit, integration-testing, nunit-3.0

We have an integration test suite that contains numerous tests executing repository classes.

The objective is to have a [OneTimeSetup] method in the BaseTestFixture, that will create/populate each target database (Postgres/SQL Server) only once before all tests and teardown after all tests.

Got this error:

> nunit OneTimeSetUp: SetUp and TearDown methods must not have parameters

How can we run the entire test suite against Postgres, SQL server and both without duplicating tests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I can't really think of an 'out-the-box' solution myself

One simple workaround would be to do two separate console runs and use the `--params` flag. That way, you could run a different setup for each database type, dependent on the `TestParameters` value passed in.

A nicer alternative may be to implement a custom attribute, which would allow you to parameterize SetUpFixtures. (There's an existing discussion on adding this feature [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1300)- although it hasn't garnered much interest since 2016.) I think it would be reasonably possible to do this as a custom attribute without modifying NUnit however.

Take a look at how [SetUpFixtureAttribute](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/15175cba113b3937862d2f258320429658ce7440/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Attributes/SetUpFixtureAttribute.cs) is implemented. I would think you'd want to create your own `IFixtureBuilder` attribute which works in a similar way, except can be parameterised, and return two suites, with a different setup for each database. I think that would work, although it's not functionality I'm totally familiar with myself.

Comment: Thanks, --params option works great. During development with ReSharper Test runner, I used Resharper environment variables to pass in the parameter. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Reference__Options__Tools__Unit_Testing__Test_Runner.html